# java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection ibatis

Tags: database-connection, ibatis, weblogic-10.x, spring-3

We are seeing a strange behavior in our prod environment only.
The application runs fine for several hours and after that we start seeing 
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection

This is happening with our spring + ibatis code base( we migrated from Hibernate to iBatis).

we are using weblogic 10.0.3, spring 3.0.2 and iBatis 2.3.5

The behavior of the exceptions are:

1. Couple of database exceptions while update ( single update not transaction) using iBatis.
2. Then java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
3. Then Cause: java.sql.SQLException: No more data to read from socket
4. Then Cause: java.sql.SQLException: OALL8 is in an inconsistent state.
5. Then Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Broken pipe.

and then all subsequent database queries getting

Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection and after then we have to restart the servers to bring the connections alive.